# How can I add information underneath the user's name on the users.php page?

Tags: filters, users

I know how to add columns to the users.php users page with `manage_users_columns` and `manage_users_custom_column`, but I don't know to modify the information shown in the default columns (e.g. username, name, email, etc.).

How can I add text as shown by the red "some text here" text in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A Replica Of The Name Column In `WP_Users_List_Table`

I think we'll have to remove the current *Name* column and add in our own column instead.

Here are the steps:

### Step #1

First we add in our own custom *Name* column and then remove the default *Name* column. Here I use the array slicing trick, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783125/2078474), to do it in a single sweep:

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', function( $columns )
{
    return array_slice( $columns, 0, 2, true ) 
        + [ 'mycol' => __( 'Name' ) ] 
        + array_slice( $columns, 3, null, true );
} );
```

### Step #2

Then we need to display the *first-* and *lastname* of the corresponding user, together with the extra "*Some text here*" message:

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', function( $output, $column_name, $user_id )
{
    if( 'mycol' === $column_name )
    {
        $u = new WP_User( $user_id ); 
        if( $u instanceof \WP_User )
        {
            // Default output
            $output .= "$u->first_name $u->last_name";

            // Extra output
            $output .= "<p>Some text here!</p>";

            // Housecleaning
            unset( $u ); 
        }
    }       
    return $output;
}, 10, 3 );
```

### Step #3

Then we only need to adjust the sortable columns with:

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', function( $columns )
{
    $columns['mycol'] = 'name';
    return $columns;
} );
```

to handle the `name` sorting, that's already supported by the public `orderby` query varaiable:

```
/wp-admin/users.php?orderby=name&order=asc
```

and

```
/wp-admin/users.php?orderby=name&order=desc
```

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Are you saying there's no way to filter the existing display and add our own content then?

Comment: I skimmed through source of `WP_List_Table` and `WP_Users_List_Table`, and specifically the `WP_Users_List_Table::single_row()` method, but couldn't find a suitable entry point for this kind of text injection. The    @j08691

Comment: This works great in functions.php, but when I added it as a plugin I had to change the priority of the `manage_users_custom_column` filter to something higher than 10 (11 seemed fine). Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you and thanks for the status update @j08691